# how can I add contextual links to each of the items in my view?

Tags: users

I am creating a view in drupal and I need that each of the items of this view (are publications) have a contextual link to access more easily to edit this publication. I have tried adding {{title_suffix.contextual_links }} in the twig, however the contextual links appear one on top of the other and it doesn't allow to edit well.
I need help please

Answer (score 2):

Rendering the links is only one half of the equation.

Contextual links are positioned absolutely. The easiest solution is to make sure that each item has the `contextual-region` class on it's wrapper.

I bet that your view has this wrapper, but none of your items do. The result is that all of the contextual links get positioned at the top right of your view rather than the top right of each item.

Comment: oh thank you very much, it worked great